# How do you use knockout mapping to map from a null value to an empty observable array?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a problem when I'm trying to use knockout mapping to map from a null json property to a knockout observable array.  After the mapping has been performed, the knockout array is null.

So, for example, I have the following data:

```
var data = { 'Name': 'David', 'Modules': null };
```

And the following models:

```
var ModuleViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
};

var Model = function(data) {

    var self = this;

    var mapping = {
      'Modules': {
        key: function(module) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(module.Id);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new ModuleViewModel(options.data);
        }
      }
    };

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);
};
```

Which is then applied to the view using:

```
var model = new Model(data);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

And in the view, simply:

```
<span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
<span data-bind="text: Modules().length"></span>
```

What I would like to see (after my name) is the number of modules that have been mapped.  If modules were present in the data:

```
var data = { 'Name': 'David', 'Modules': [ {'Id': '1', 'Name': 'Module1'} ] }
```

then the correct number is displayed on the view, but if the modules are set to null in the data then the number is not displayed at all as it does not know to map to an observable array.

Additionally, if I define an extra property on my view model to map to:

```
self.Modules = ko.observableArray;
```

this still does not get mapped as I expect as if you query `self.Modules()` after the mapping you get a `null` value returned when if you query a normal empty observable array you get `[]` returned.

What am I doing wrong in the mapping?  I would just like a 0 value to be displayed when the modules data is null.

[Click here to edit using jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gubofotayo/1/edit)

Comment: You could change your binding. `<span data-bind="text: (Modules() || []).length"></span>`

Comment: you could, but that's not really helping him with the mapping operations

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to point out that you don't necessarily need to change your mapping to make your bindings work. Sometimes it's better to make your bindings flexible enough to work with different mappings.

Comment: When you're using the mapping plugin, you cannot have `null` or `undefined` values, the plugin will only work if a key has a value. You need to ensure that you actually have data if you want to use it correctly.

Comment: @JeffMercado Null is also data, a property value can vary between having value and being null. This is bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little update to your mappings that you might find useful.

http://jsbin.com/zeguxiveyi/1

It's important to note the following changes.

For one, you weren't applying your mapping.

```
// need to invoke the mapping object
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);
```

Secondly, it doesn't make a lot of sense to invoke an observable with null...it's like eating the hole of a donut, right?

```
//Initialize your data with null modules :: ERROR
//For the sake of having an empty observable array, we need to convert this null to an empty array
var data = { 'Name': 'David', 'Modules': null };
if(data.Modules == null) data.Modules = [];
```

Thirdly, in the case where you may be getting nulls, you should go ahead and add a little short-circuit logic to prevent it...

```
var mapping = {
 'Modules': {
    create: function (options) {
      if(options.data !== null)
        return new ModuleViewModel(options.data);
    }
  }
};
```

All in all, the mapping plugin is useful, but there's nothing magical about it...still need to be sure your data is reasonable.

Comment: Regarding your first point, I have updated the question and the fiddle to include the mapping.  This was just another mistake when creating the fiddle.

Comment: Regarding your second point, your right, I'm trying to cater for bad data.  I realise now that my data should have been `var data = { 'Name': 'David', 'Modules': []};` with an empty array rather than null.  I have gone back to the source to ensure that when my data is serialised an empty array is provided.  That way, I don't have to provide these front end workarounds.

Comment: Your second point: Sure it does, if you have an object where a property can change between being an object and being null, remapping it will destroy the observable and as a consequence all connections to subscribers of that property. Having to manually check these cases sucks.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a computed observable for null checking and to keep it as clean as possible, like this:

```
var ModuleViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    //After mapping the object, add the computed observable here
    self.numberOfModules = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.Modules ? this.Modules().length : 0;
    }, self);
};
```

Then in your binding:

```
<span data-bind="text: numberOfModules">
```

This is specially handy if the computed is used in many different places in the HTML in order to avoid duplicating null checks everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I did have something similar to this at one point but it did feel like something was a little wrong.  Following beauXjames answer I realised that it was the source data that was wrong and that when I corrected the data to be an empty array [] rather than null all my problems went away. Thanks for the answer though.